# How do i get foreign Country address in a specific language in MyPtv GeoCodingApi?

Tags: ptv-developer

I'm using MyPtv GeoCoding Api: for example I search for greek address in german language

```
LocationsApi.SearchLocationsByAddress
    Country:"GR", 
    State:"Kentriki Makedonia", 
    PostalCode:"546 45", 
    City:"Thessaloniki", 
    Street:"Voga Kimonos",
    HouseNumber:"36",
    language: "de"
```

i get response where  German and Greek are mixed.
[image]
It looks like thet geolocation service has all information i need(it finds the correct geolocation using German Address). But response is weird. Do i need some additinal Settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider to apply the "language" parameter:

```
LocationsSearchResult locationsSearchResult = 
            locationsApi.SearchLocationsByAddress(
            country: "GR",
            state: "Kentriki Makedonia",
            postalCode : "546 45",
            locality : "Thessaloniki",
            street : "Voga Kimonos",
            houseNumber: "36",
            language : "und-Latn-t-el"
        );
```

There are some other specific transcriptions available, such as
"und-Latn-t-uk" - specifies Ukrainian transliterated to latin alphabet

"und-Latn-t-ru" - specifies Russian transliterated to latin alphabet

Here's another relevant document:
https://xserver2-europe-eu-test.cloud.ptvgroup.com/dashboard/Default.htm#TechnicalConcepts/Basics/DSC_Language_Codes.htm?Highlight=maplanguage

[image: your example with the returned values]